# UWP app for recievering messages from Azure IoT hub

Tags: c#, azure, win-universal-app, azure-iot-hub

I want to make UWP app for receivering messages from Azure IoT hub. 
I found example code for Console receiver App, but it doesn't work with UWP, because UWP do not support this refference

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
```

Can someone post code for UWP app for receivering messages from Azure IoT hub?

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a couple posts doing this. Check out both of these:

- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/03/connect-your-windows-app-to-azure-iot-hub-with-visual-studio/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/iot-hub-dotnet-uwp-remote-monitoring/

Answer (score 1):

You can try AzureSBLite, you can install this from NuGet package manager.

https://github.com/ppatierno/azuresblite

Sample Code for receiving:

```
string ConnectionString = "<EventHub-Compatible-EndPoint>;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey<Key>
    static string eventHubEntity = "<EventHub-Compatible-Name>";
    string partitionId = "0";
    DateTime startingDateTimeUtc;
    EventHubConsumerGroup group;
    EventHubClient client;
    MessagingFactory factory;
    EventHubReceiver receiver;

public async Task ReceiveDataFromCloud()
    {
        startingDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
        builder.TransportType = ppatierno.AzureSBLite.Messaging.TransportType.Amqp;

        factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);

        client = factory.CreateEventHubClient(eventHubEntity);
        group = client.GetDefaultConsumerGroup();
        receiver = group.CreateReceiver(partitionId.ToString(), startingDateTimeUtc);//startingDateTimeUtc
        while (true)
        {
            EventData data = receiver.Receive();

            if (data != null)
            {
                var receiveddata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.GetBytes());

                Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", data.SequenceNumber, data.EnqueuedTimeUtc.ToLocalTime(), Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.GetBytes()));

            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            await Task.Delay(2000);

        }

        receiver.Close();
        client.Close();
        factory.Close();

    }
```

You can get EventHub-Compatible-Endpoint and EventHub-Compatible Name from IoTHub settings-> Messaging section. In that under Device to cloud settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue.I couldn't receive message Azure IOT hub.Because AMQP is not supporting in UWP.
I have tried below sample.But i dont have luck to receive message.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/device/samples/UWPSample

Please let me know,If you have received message in UWP.
Is it plan to support AMQP in UWP?When will give this update?

Comment: why you putting same answer as above

Answer (score 0):

Receiving messages sent **by the cloud to the device** is supported in the official SDK using the HTTP endpoint. See:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/device/samples/UWPSample

Receiving messages sent **by the device to the cloud** is trickier because it's an AMQP endpoint but can be done using AMQPNetLite:

https://paolopatierno.wordpress.com/2015/10/31/azure-iot-hub-commands-and-feedback-using-amqp-net-lite/

Answer (score 0):

This is Best way to receive messages from iot. there are two way to do this `C2D` and `D2C`... cloud to device and device to cloud. It depends on your requirement. Code is full tested by me:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //txtblkMessages.Text = "test";
        Start();
    }

    private static int MESSAGE_COUNT = 1;

    private const string DeviceConnectionString = "HostName=[your hostname];DeviceId=[your DeviceId];SharedAccessKey=[your shared key]";
    public async Task Start()
    {
        try
        {
            DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(DeviceConnectionString, TransportType.Amqp);
            //await SendEvent(deviceClient);
            await ReceiveCommands(deviceClient);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error in sample: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    async Task SendEvent(DeviceClient deviceClient)
    {
        string dataBuffer;
        //for (int count = 0; count < MESSAGE_COUNT; count++)
        //{
        dataBuffer = "Hello Iot";
        Message eventMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataBuffer));
        await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(eventMessage);
        // }
    }

    async Task ReceiveCommands(DeviceClient deviceClient)
    {
        Message receivedMessage;
        string messageData;
        while (true)
        {
            receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
            if (receivedMessage != null)
            {
                messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());
                txtblkMessages.Text = messageData + "\n" + txtblkMessages.Text;
                await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
            }
            //  Note: In this sample, the polling interval is set to 
            //  10 seconds to enable you to see messages as they are sent.
            //  To enable an IoT solution to scale, you should extend this //  interval. For example, to scale to 1 million devices, set 
            //  the polling interval to 25 minutes.
            //  For further information, see
            //  https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/iot-hub-devguide/#messaging
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check source code of the UWP application I created:

https://github.com/Daniel-Krzyczkowski/WindowsIoTCore/blob/master/AzureTruckIoT/AzureTruckIoT.SensorsApp/Cloud/CloudDataService.cs

CloudDataService class contains two methods and uses IoT Hub SDK:

- SendDataToTheCloud
- ReceiveDataFromTheCloud

This is an example how to send and receive messages with UWP app and IoT Hub.